# Remote Desktop for Mac OS X

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop

Is there any remote desktop solution for Mac? I don't mean a VNC where one can only manage the computer using the logged user on the computer. I want to be able to use my Mac at home using GUI with my account while my wife accesses the computer locally using her account.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mac OS X does not support multiple GUI sessions by itself. There are a couple options however - you can try [Vine Server](http://www.testplant.com/products/vine%5Fviewer/multidesktop) which requires some setup ahead of time (fast user switching on, you have to be logged on with a copy of Vine Server running).

The more robust alternative is a product called [AquaConnect Terminal Server](http://www.aquaconnect.net/) which provides services like Terminal Server but requires Mac OS  X Server to run.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps but there "might" be away if X11 is turned on on the Mac as any unix/linux os disto would usually work. would need some unconventional setup though. Oh and you probably would not get the same OS X desktop presented when connected via X11. Just throwing out and idea...my apologies if this misses the mark.(i would know how to setup multiple sessions on unix/linux but never done it with mac)

Answer (score 1):

www.logmein.com

but I'm afraid to use multiple GUI same time you need Mac OS X server:)

Comment: Hi Stalker, could you point me to the documentation of LogMeIn where it says it supports multiple GUI on Mac? thx

Comment: logmein.com as all similar services does not provide multiple GUI. Only work with current logged in user. Even with server version or apple remote desktop software only one GUI what is currently logging in.
As previous poster said. To make it happened you do need:

Mac OS X Server version
AquaConnect Terminal Server software (depends what version of server you want to use)